# I'm having a lot of trouble trying using scale_y_datetime not show geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, powerbi, geom-bar

I'm having a lot of trouble trying using `scale_y_datetime` not show `geom_bar` show message remove 30 rows
and trying `coord_cartesian` of trouble upside down.

> Warning message:
> Removed 30 rows containing missing values (geom_bar).

My raw data is character strings of the format:

```
> dataset
                          Date      Duration Time
1  2020-06-01T00:00:00.0000000 1899-12-31T04:43:00.0000000
2  2020-06-02T00:00:00.0000000 1899-12-31T04:37:00.0000000
3  2020-06-03T00:00:00.0000000 1899-12-31T04:25:00.0000000
4  2020-06-04T00:00:00.0000000 1899-12-31T04:48:00.0000000
5  2020-06-05T00:00:00.0000000 1899-12-31T04:52:00.0000000
6  2020-06-06T00:00:00.0000000 1899-12-31T05:19:00.0000000
7  2020-06-07T00:00:00.0000000 1899-12-31T04:25:00.0000000
8  2020-06-08T00:00:00.0000000 1899-12-31T04:43:00.0000000
9  2020-06-09T00:00:00.0000000 1899-12-31T05:26:00.0000000
10 2020-06-10T00:00:00.0000000 1899-12-31T04:26:00.0000000
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjgU6.png]

```
 Sys.setenv(TZ='UTC')
    library(scales)
    library(ggplot2)
    library(reshape2) 
        Day=format(as.POSIXct(dataset$'Date', format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S",tz="UTC"), format="%y-%b-%d")
        Hour=as.POSIXct(dataset$'Duration Time', format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S",tz="UTC")
        lima1 = c(as.POSIXct("1899-12-31T01:00:00",format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S",tz="UTC"),as.POSIXct("1899-12-31T08:00:00",format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S",tz="UTC"))
        DurationTime <- c(Hour)
        day <- c(Day)
    
    df1 <- data.frame(DurationTime, day)
    df <- melt(df1, id.vars = "day")
    head(df)
    start_time = strptime("1899-12-31 02:00:00", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    breaks = seq(0, 6, length.out = 7)
    labels = c( "02:00", "03:00", 
               "04:00", "05:00", "06:00", "07:00", "08:00")
    dataFrame <- data.frame(df)
    names(dataFrame) <- c("day","Variable","Value")
    #dataFrame$Time <- dataFrame$Value
    #dataFrame$TimeInSeconds <- as.difftime(dataFrame$Time - start_time)
    
    ggplot(data = dataFrame,aes(x = dataFrame$'day', 
                                     y = as.POSIXct(dataFrame$'Value', format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S",tz="UTC"),
                                     fill = Variable)) + 
      geom_bar(stat="identity",position = 'dodge') +
      geom_text(aes(label=format(as.POSIXct(dataFrame$'Value', format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S",tz="UTC"), format="%H:%M")), position=position_dodge(width=0.9), hjust =-0.10,angle=90) + 
      #scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 6),breaks = breaks,labels = labels)
      #coord_cartesian(ylim=c(as.POSIXct("1899-12-31T01:00:00",format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"),as.POSIXct("1899-12-31T08:00:00",format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"))) +
      scale_y_datetime(limits=c(as.POSIXct("1899-12-31T01:00:00",format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"),as.POSIXct("1899-12-31T08:00:00",format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")),breaks=date_breaks("1 hour"),labels=date_format("%H:%M", tz = "UTC"))+
    
      theme_bw()+
    xlab("Day") +
    ylab("Time") +
    labs(fill="Legend") +
    theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90))+
    theme(axis.text.y=element_text(angle=45))+
      theme(legend.position = 'bottom')+
      theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),panel.background = element_blank())
```

I'm using `ylim` `coord_cartesian` it upside down I don't want to upside down.
I want the normal vertical.

```
coord_cartesian(ylim=c(as.POSIXct("1899-12-31T01:00:00",format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"),as.POSIXct("1899-12-31T08:00:00",format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"))) +
  scale_y_datetime(breaks=date_breaks("1 hour"),labels=date_format("%H:%M", tz = "UTC"))+
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIq4Z.png]

Comment: Hello there! You need to provide a reproducible example: I need to be able to run a code and get your result. Also you need to specify what result you want to achieve. You just want the same graph but flipped upside down? About the 30 missing rows, you have 30 NAs in your data. ggplot can't plot them so it removes those rows.

Comment: I understand that display time is incorrect  make it geom_bar 30 missing rows not displayed.
I don't want to upside down. I want the normal vertical.

Comment: unrelated, but you shouldn't be using `$` in the `aes`

Comment: Thanks. I will try to avoid using $ in the aes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it.

The reason why you see the bars upside down is because ggplot doesnt understand dates. Ggplot sees numbers: converts dates to numbers.
Those duration times converted to numbers are negative. Therefore the bars are correctly towards the negative side.

The solution is to make your duration dates to start from the "zero" date of R.

Look at this reproducible example here:
[I kept all your themes and settings of the chart]

```
library(scales)
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2) 
library(lubridate) 
library(dplyr) 


dataset <- tibble::tribble(~Date, ~`Duration Time`,
                           "2020-06-01T00:00:00.0000000", "1899-12-31T04:43:00.0000000",
                           "2020-06-02T00:00:00.0000000", "1899-12-31T04:37:00.0000000",
                           "2020-06-03T00:00:00.0000000", "1899-12-31T04:25:00.0000000",
                           "2020-06-04T00:00:00.0000000", "1899-12-31T04:48:00.0000000",
                           "2020-06-05T00:00:00.0000000", "1899-12-31T04:52:00.0000000",
                           "2020-06-06T00:00:00.0000000", "1899-12-31T05:19:00.0000000",
                           "2020-06-07T00:00:00.0000000", "1899-12-31T04:25:00.0000000",
                           "2020-06-08T00:00:00.0000000", "1899-12-31T04:43:00.0000000",
                           "2020-06-09T00:00:00.0000000", "1899-12-31T05:26:00.0000000",
                           "2020-06-10T00:00:00.0000000", "1899-12-31T04:26:00.0000000")


dataset <- dataset %>%
  mutate(Day = as_date(Date),
         `Duration Time` = as_datetime(`Duration Time`)) %>% 
  mutate(Time = make_datetime(hour = hour(`Duration Time`), 
                              min = minute(`Duration Time`),
                              sec = second(`Duration Time`)))
  

ggplot(data = dataset,
       aes(x = Day, 
           y = Time)) + 
  geom_bar(fill = "steelblue", stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label = format(Time, format="%H:%M")), position=position_dodge(width=0.9), hjust =-0.10,angle=90) + 
  theme_bw() +
  xlab("Day") +
  ylab("Time") +
  labs(fill="Legend") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))+
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(angle = 45))+
  theme(legend.position = 'bottom')+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I can understand progressive. But do you have a way  to start at 23:00 or not? I have a plan to build create graph, for example StopA 23:00, StopB  at 5:00. I'm trying using fill variable df1 <- data.frame(StopA,StopB, Date) df <- melt(df1, id.vars = "Date") but this it start at 00:00 .You are enough to have a way to set it to start at 11:00 pm or another time nonzero ?

Comment: You can add this to the chart to start from 23 `scale_y_datetime(labels = function(x) format(x - dhours(1), format = "%H:%M"))` and this to start from 5 `scale_y_datetime(labels = function(x) format(x + dhours(5), format = "%H:%M"))`. It's not really clean imho but it gets the work done.

Comment: Thank you so much. Display of graph great.